# Auto display Age based on the birthdate field using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Here are the HTML code and the JavaScript. How to auto compute the age and display the computed age in age field after selecting the birthdate.I tried many times but still the age can't display in the field.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthdate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthdate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", id = "birthdate-input", max = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age-output" readonly />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



 <script>
            function calculateAge(birthdate) {
                var today = new Date();
                var birthdateDate = new Date(birthdate);
                var age = today.getFullYear() - birthdateDate.getFullYear();
                var birthMonth = birthdateDate.getMonth() + 1;
                var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;

                if (todayMonth < birthMonth || (todayMonth === birthMonth && today.getDate() < birthdateDate.getDate())) {
                    age--;
                }

                return age;
            }

            $(function () {
                $('#birthdate-input').change(function () {
                    var birthdate = $(this).val();
                    var age = calculateAge(birthdate);
                    console.log(age); // Add this line to check if age is computed correctly
                    $('#age-output').val(age);
                });

                // Compute age on page load if birthdate is already set
                var birthdate = $('#birthdate-input').val();
                if (birthdate) {
                    var age = calculateAge(birthdate);
                    console.log(age); // Add this line to check if age is computed correctly
                    $('#age-output').val(age);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you used your JS debugger? If not, **why not**?